# Unsuccessful creating tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and im trying to create the below tables.  The player and venue table work but the goals, matches and teams does not.  Is it due to the the foreign keys or something else?  Tables goals teamh and teamA reference table matches(teamh and teamA) and table matches reference table teams (teamname)

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYER (
PlayerID int NOT NULL,
Playername varchar (255),
Playersurname varchar (255),
Teamname varchar (255),
Age int,
Nationality varchar (255),
Primary key (PlayerID)
);

CREATE TABLE GOALS (
TeamH varchar (255),
TeamA varchar (255),
PlayerID int,
Minute time,
Primary key (Minute),
Foreign key (TeamH) references MATCHES(TeamH),
Foreign key (TeamA) references MATCHES(TeamA),
Foreign key (PlayerId) references PLAYER(PlayerID)
);

CREATE TABLE MATCHES (
TeamH varchar (255),
TeamA varchar (255),
GoalH int,
GoalA int,
Mdate date,
VenueName varchar (255),
Attendance varchar (255),
Primary key (TeamH, TeamA),
Foreign key (TeamH) references TEAMS(Teamname),
Foreign key (TeamA) references TEAMS(Teamname),
Foreign key (Venuename) references VENUES(Venuename)
);

CREATE TABLE TEAMS (
Teamname varchar (255),
Year date,
President varchar (255),
Primary key (Teamname)
);


CREATE TABLE VENUES (
Venuename varchar(255),
Capacity int,
Address varchar (255),
primary key (venuename)
);
```

Comment: It looks like it's just the order of you `CREATE TABLE` statements that are causing the problem due to foreign key references - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48704306/110495

Comment: Could you please mark either answer as a working answer so that others do not spend time answering a question that has 2 working solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are trying to create the tables with foreign keys before the foreign key tables have been created, does the following work?

```
-- first create the primary tables, PLAYER, TEAMS, VENUES
CREATE TABLE PLAYER (
PlayerID int NOT NULL,
Playername varchar (255),
Playersurname varchar (255),
Teamname varchar (255),
Age int,
Nationality varchar (255),
Primary key (PlayerID)
);

CREATE TABLE TEAMS (
Teamname varchar (255),
Year date,
President varchar (255),
Primary key (Teamname)
);    

CREATE TABLE VENUES (
Venuename varchar(255),
Capacity int,
Address varchar (255),
primary key (venuename)
);

-- Now create the foreign key using tables, MATCHES, GOALS
CREATE TABLE MATCHES (
TeamH varchar (255),
TeamA varchar (255),
GoalH int,
GoalA int,
Mdate date,
VenueName varchar (255),
Attendance varchar (255),
Primary key (TeamH, TeamA),
Foreign key (TeamH) references TEAMS(Teamname),
Foreign key (TeamA) references TEAMS(Teamname),
Foreign key (Venuename) references VENUES(Venuename)
);

CREATE TABLE GOALS (
TeamH varchar (255),
TeamA varchar (255),
PlayerID int,
Minute time,
Primary key (Minute),
Foreign key (TeamH) references MATCHES(TeamH),
Foreign key (TeamA) references MATCHES(TeamA),
Foreign key (PlayerId) references PLAYER(PlayerID)
);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan,  the player and venue table are good. i have greyed out the goals and matches table and the teams still doesn't work

Comment: CREATE TABLE TEAMS (
Teamname varchar (255),
Yearoffoundation date,
President varchar (255),
Primary key (Teamname)
);

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your tables out of order.  Your various `CREATE TABLE` statements refer to other tables, and those tables need to exist at the time the statement is called.  Try using this order:

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYER
CREATE TABLE TEAMS
CREATE TABLE VENUES
CREATE TABLE MATCHES   -- refers to TEAMS and VENUES
CREATE TABLE GOALS     -- refers to MATCHES and PLAYER
```

Comment: hi tim,  no such luck.  Venues and player is created but i get an error message for teams

Comment: CREATE TABLE TEAMS (
Teamname varchar (255),
Yearoffoundation date,
President varchar (255),
Primary key (Teamname)
);

Comment: i have greyed out matches and goals before refreshing teams

Comment: What is the error message you see when you run `CREATE TABLE TEAMS` ?

Comment: The error message was re the db connection but i didn't see the whole message till i tried to copy it.  Issue resolved.  Thank you!

Comment: @Clonew You should mark one of these answers correct and/or upvote.